# Mass portscans on ephemeral ports... why?

Tags: networking, firewall, sonicwall

I recently got a new account and took over management of their space, including the sonicwall.

First thing's first, we updated the firmware as the prior admin hadn't been keeping up... lovely :)

So, in the wave of reconfigure-the-sonicwall-to-actually-be-a-security-appliance, I turned on IDS and event alerts.

My box has exploded with scan alerts.
Here are a few.

What's strange is the alerts appear to have the following characteristics:
Usually originating on a web port, 80 and 443
Targeting the public-facing IP
This is a US based customer of mine with global clientele, but I'm who.is'ing the IPs and seeing stuff from Iceland to China.

Can someone provide some clarity as to a legitimate service that the IDS has mistook?  Originally, IDS hosed all SIP traffic until I excluded the off-site PBX, so I wouldn't be surprised if IDS is hosing more things and the users just don't notice or report.

```
04/18/2019 19:25:05 - 82 - Security Services - Alert - 77.247.109.151, 7659, X2 - XXX.178, 19090, X2 - udp - UDP scanned port list, 8080, 9060, 9070, 9080, 17070 - Possible port scan detected

This email was generated by: SonicOS Enhanced 6.5.3.1-48n (18B1-6993-2800)



04/18/2019 17:54:06 - 82 - Security Services - Alert - 198.61.165.71, 443, X2 - XXX.180, 64982, X2 - tcp - TCP scanned port list, 41016, 18069, 26794, 56346, 14356 - Possible port scan detected

This email was generated by: SonicOS Enhanced 6.5.3.1-48n (18B1-6993-2800)



04/18/2019 17:13:58 - 83 - Security Services - Alert - 5.8.18.90, 65532, X2 - XXX.180, 3364, X2 - tcp - TCP scanned port list, 3363, 3362, 3357, 3365, 3358, 3359, 3360, 3355, 3361, 3364 - Probable port scan detected

This email was generated by: SonicOS Enhanced 6.5.3.1-48n (18B1-6993-2800)



04/18/2019 17:13:58 - 82 - Security Services - Alert - 5.8.18.90, 65532, X2 - XXX.180, 3359, X2 - tcp - TCP scanned port list, 3363, 3362, 3357, 3365, 3358 - Possible port scan detected

This email was generated by: SonicOS Enhanced 6.5.3.1-48n (18B1-6993-2800)



04/18/2019 15:55:46 - 82 - Security Services - Alert - 205.180.85.169, 443, X2 - XXX.180, 52468, X2 - tcp - TCP scanned port list, 19366, 65141, 17474, 5725, 57646 - Possible port scan detected

This email was generated by: SonicOS Enhanced 6.5.3.1-48n (18B1-6993-2800)



04/18/2019 14:52:53 - 82 - Security Services - Alert - 151.101.5.140, 443, X2 - XXX.180, 36862, X2 - tcp - TCP scanned port list, 18568, 29110, 40462, 10585, 26896 - Possible port scan detected

This email was generated by: SonicOS Enhanced 6.5.3.1-48n (18B1-6993-2800)
```

Comment: Ensure that those connections with source ports 80 and 443 aren't timed out outgoing connections to http and https websites which the connection tracking has forgotten about; some firewalls are really bad at that. Otherwise it might be that the scan is done from those ports in the silly assumption that traffic coming in from those ports are open in your firewall (maybe in the 1990's that may have been common, with stateful firewalls this should not be the case). Ignore these scans unless a particular source is continually targetting you, in which case you simply block its network.

Answer (score 0):

I manage multiple sonicwall and those alerts are pretty common with any sonicwall on the internet.

Usually it’s not the IDS that trigger those alerts.

They are coming usually from botnet that actively scan any host alive.
 Keep in mind the sonicwall report it to you, but it’s just a warning, nothing got blocked.